# Is it possible to replace an image with another one selected by the user on the fly via jQuery alone?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having the user select an image and I want to change the one shown on the fly without having to rely on server-side scripts like PHP?

Basically, I have an HTML that has something like the following:

```
<input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
<img id="imagedisplay" src="http://path/to/some/image.jpg" />
```

Then on the jQuery side I have the following:

```
$('#file').change(function(e){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

I was hoping to replace the `imagedisplay`'s `src` with the one the user selects referenced locally to their system but `$(this).val()` only displays the file name so I won't be able to reference it as the source.

Comment: You can't do it that way. You need to upload the image into the browsers memory to be able to display it. Have a look [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/), it has some more information but also how to upload your file to the browser.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) API.

> The FileReader object lets web applications asynchronously read the contents of files (or raw data buffers) stored on the user's computer.

Its method [FileReader.readAsDataURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL)

> The `readAsDataURL` method is used to read the contents of the specified Blob or File.

Note: It works in Modern browsers

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#file').change(function(e) {

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('#imagedisplay').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
<img id="imagedisplay" src="" />
```