# Is it possible to show image in fancybox after upload and before submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

**form.html**

```
<input type="file" name="img" onchange="previewFile(this)" >
<a href="#">Preview</a>
```

After It uploads I want to show it in `fancybox` on click of preview. I add `fancybox` on existing images but how to add on upload images?

For existing images I use and it works

```
$("a.fancybox").fancybox();
```

Comment: show us what you have done so far mate

Comment: _Is it possible_ Answer is __Yes__,

Comment: @Satpal how?    .....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29509357 in the answer I have provided example how you can preview uploaded image

Comment: what you could do is get the path of the image you have uploaded and then pass it to your `a` tag

Comment: I already done that. I want to apply fancybox on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use img tag for the preview of the image

```js
var previewFile = function(event) {
    var output = document.getElementById('output');
    output.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
    };
```

```html
 <input type="file" name="img" onchange="previewFile(event)" > <br>
   <a class="fancybox"><img id="output" alt="Preview Image" width="300" height="300"/></a>
```

Comment: How to apply fancy box on this provew_img?

Comment: i dont know if it will work but you can enclose it with a img tag example:
<a href="google.html"><img id="output" alt="Preview Image" width="300" height="300"/></a>